# Request[variable] - weird behavior

Tags: c#, linq, request

I have the following lines of code:

```
myProducts = myProducts.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Tags) && p.Tags.Contains(string.Format("{0}={1}|", "brand-name", "38")));
myProducts = myProducts.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Tags) && p.Tags.Contains(string.Format("{0}={1}|", channel.Alias, Request[channel.Alias])));
Response.Write(string.Format("'{0}={1}|'", "brand-name", "38") + "\n\r");
Response.Write(string.Format("'{0}={1}|'", channel.Alias, Request[channel.Alias]) + "\n\r");
```

The second line of code, does not work, even though both of the `response.write` shows the same result.

Please help me with this one, it seems im lost in this.

Comment: Define "does not work", what happens?

Comment: well, i get nothing back. which is wrong, since in the 1st line of code, it works and i get one product back.

Comment: Can you tell us what `Request[channel.Alias]` actually returns?

Comment: both of the `.write` return 'brand-name=38|' , so to your question, `Request[channel.Alias]` returns `38`

Comment: Do these pass? `Debug.Assert(channel.Alias.ToString().Equals("brand-name", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));` and `Debug.Assert(Request[channel.Alias].Equals("38", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));`?  You may have some extra spaces on there that need to be trimmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the love of god,
this works for some reason, cant figure out why....

```
var value = string.Format("{0}={1}|", channel.Alias, Request[channel.Alias]);

myProducts = myProducts.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Tags) && p.Tags.Contains(value));
```